# How to solve: Type error: 'Draggable' cannot be used as a JSX component ? (react-draggable)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, jsx, draggable

I get this error while building this Next.js React project

```
Type error: 'Draggable' cannot be used as a JSX component.
    Its instance type 'Draggable' is not a valid JSX element.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
            Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/app/node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
                Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

We weren't getting this error before, and the code and the dependencies are the same.
What could be happening?

This is my package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "build+start": "next build && next start",
        "type-check": "tsc --pretty --noEmit",
        "format": "prettier --write .",
        "lint": "eslint --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern 'src/**/*.{tsx,ts}'",
        "test": "jest",
        "test-all": "yarn lint && yarn type-check && yarn test",
        "build:widget": "webpack --config ./src/widgets/webpack.config.js",
        "prepare": "husky install"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.2.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "@segment/analytics.js-core": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
        "@segment/analytics.js-integration-segmentio": "^4.2.5",
        "@segment/snippet": "^4.13.1",
        "@types/analytics-node": "^3.1.6",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
        "@types/segment-analytics": "^0.0.33",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
        "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
        "analytics-node": "^5.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.20.0",
        "formik": "^2.2.0",
        "graphql": "^15.3.0",
        "mobx": "^5.15.4",
        "mobx-react": "^6.2.2",
        "moment": "^2.29.0",
        "next": "9.5.3",
        "next-absolute-url": "^1.2.2",
        "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
        "player.js": "^0.1.0",
        "postcss": "^8.2.15",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-draggable": "^4.4.3",
        "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.14.1",
        "react-player": "^2.9.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
        "sass": "^1.35.2",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.4.0",
        "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.18",
        "uuid": "^3.4",
        "webpack": "4.44.1",
        "xml": "^1.0.1",
        "yup": "^0.29.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.1",
        "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
        "@types/node": "^13.9.5",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.27",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "^25.2.3",
        "css-modules-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.4",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.5.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^10.0.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "^11.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "husky": "^7.0.4",
        "jest": "^25.2.3",
        "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.5.0",
        "lint-staged": "^10.0.10",
        "prettier": "^2.1.1",
        "prettier-stylelint": "^0.4.2",
        "sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
        "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "stylelint": "^13.7.0",
        "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
        "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^7.1.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
        "stylelint-prettier": "^1.1.2",
        "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
        "ts-loader": "^8.0.1",
        "typescript": "^4.3.3",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you create a codesandbox and try to recreate the issue there.. it'd be difficult to tell what's going on otherwise..

Comment: @tanmay, thanks, I might. But I'm not sure how it would help, the code is already in production and working. Now suddenly the build fails, I haven't updated the code or the dependencies.  
I inherited this project, am not a React expert, I'm more of a backend dev, I really get lost in all this bundling, SSR, dependency hell, etc.

Comment: [this thread](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33822) probably talks about a similar issue. You can try some of the suggestions out, see if it works.

Comment: @tanmay, thanks, I'll take a look, but we've been using "@types/react": "^16.9.27" for the last year and a half, in production, without issues.
That issue is for @types/react@16.8.8

Answer (score 2):

@types/react-dom has its own dependencies and one of them is @types/react with a version set to '*' - a major release

I believe you are trying to do a fresh `npm install` with no `package-lock.json` due to which there is a mismatch of `@types/react` version as it is probably referring to 18

You can resolve this by following steps:

Run `npm i force-resolutions`

In your package.json add

```
"resolutions":{
  "@types/react": "17.0.0", // or "16.9.27"
  "@types/react-dom": "17.0.9"
},
```

ADD `"preinstall": "npx force-resolutions"` to your scripts

Delete your `node_modules` and Run `npm install`

By using resolutions we are specifying strict restrictions for dependencies of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually have @types/react-dom v17.0.16 and its only dependency is "@types/react": "^17"